# Display download progress using WebClient

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, webclient

How can I display download progress using C#'s `WebClient` asynchronously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve that by using [`WebClient.DownloadProgressChangedEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.downloadprogresschangedeventargs%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Don't open the file explicitely with `OpenRead`. Instead, just call `DownloadFileAsync` like you did - the `DownloadProgressChanged` handler has `UploadProgressChangedEventArgs.TotalBytesToSend`, which you can show to the user (as well as `BytesSent` and even `ProgressPercentage`).